# Alexa does not react to wakeword

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit, lego-mindstorms-ev3

I am trying to use my Lego Mindstorms EV3 with Amazon Alexa, as they are has started a little competition.

As described on hackster.io (https://www.hackster.io/alexagadgets/lego-mindstorms-voice-challenge-mission-1-f31925) I followed all steps, flashed my sd card, import the programs and connect my EV3 with Alexa. Everything works fine, except that Alexa does not react to the Wakeword.

I do not get any errors or something and I do not know where the problem is, especially the code is a tutorial and just copy and paste.

That is the provided Code from hackster.io:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Copyright 2019 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates.  All Rights Reserved.
# 
# You may not use this file except in compliance with the terms and conditions 
# set forth in the accompanying LICENSE.TXT file.
#
# THESE MATERIALS ARE PROVIDED ON AN "AS IS" BASIS. AMAZON SPECIFICALLY DISCLAIMS, WITH 
# RESPECT TO THESE MATERIALS, ALL WARRANTIES, EXPRESS, IMPLIED, OR STATUTORY, INCLUDING 
# THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE, AND NON-INFRINGEMENT.

import os
import sys
import time
import logging

from ev3dev2.sound import Sound
from ev3dev2.led import Leds

from agt import AlexaGadget

# set logger to display on both EV3 Brick and console
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, stream=sys.stdout, format='%(message)s')
logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr))
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class MindstormsGadget(AlexaGadget):
    """
    An Mindstorms gadget that will react to the Alexa wake word.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Performs Alexa Gadget initialization routines and ev3dev resource allocation.
        """
        super().__init__()

        self.leds = Leds()
        self.sound = Sound()

    def on_connected(self, device_addr):
        """
        Gadget connected to the paired Echo device.
        :param device_addr: the address of the device we connected to
        """
        self.leds.set_color("LEFT", "GREEN")
        self.leds.set_color("RIGHT", "GREEN")
        logger.info("{} connected to Echo device".format(self.friendly_name))

    def on_disconnected(self, device_addr):
        """
        Gadget disconnected from the paired Echo device.
        :param device_addr: the address of the device we disconnected from
        """
        self.leds.set_color("LEFT", "BLACK")
        self.leds.set_color("RIGHT", "BLACK")
        logger.info("{} disconnected from Echo device".format(self.friendly_name))

    def on_alexa_gadget_statelistener_stateupdate(self, directive):
        """
        Listens for the wakeword state change and react by turning on the LED.
        :param directive: contains a payload with the updated state information from Alexa
        """
        color_list = ['BLACK', 'AMBER', 'YELLOW', 'GREEN']
        for state in directive.payload.states:
            if state.name == 'wakeword':

                if state.value == 'active':
                    print("Wake word active", file=sys.stderr)
                    self.sound.play_song((('A3', 'e'), ('C5', 'e')))
                    for i in range(0, 4, 1):
                        self.leds.set_color("LEFT", color_list[i], (i * 0.25))
                        self.leds.set_color("RIGHT", color_list[i], (i * 0.25))
                        time.sleep(0.25)

                elif state.value == 'cleared':
                    print("Wake word cleared", file=sys.stderr)
                    self.sound.play_song((('C5', 'e'), ('A3', 'e')))
                    for i in range(3, -1, -1):
                        self.leds.set_color("LEFT", color_list[i], (i * 0.25))
                        self.leds.set_color("RIGHT", color_list[i], (i * 0.25))
                        time.sleep(0.25)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    gadget = MindstormsGadget()

    # Set LCD font and turn off blinking LEDs
    os.system('setfont Lat7-Terminus12x6')
    gadget.leds.set_color("LEFT", "BLACK")
    gadget.leds.set_color("RIGHT", "BLACK")

    # Startup sequence
    gadget.sound.play_song((('C4', 'e'), ('D4', 'e'), ('E5', 'q')))
    gadget.leds.set_color("LEFT", "GREEN")
    gadget.leds.set_color("RIGHT", "GREEN")

    # Gadget main entry point
    gadget.main()

    # Shutdown sequence
    gadget.sound.play_song((('E5', 'e'), ('C4', 'e')))
    gadget.leds.set_color("LEFT", "BLACK")
    gadget.leds.set_color("RIGHT", "BLACK")
```

Comment: The "on_alexa_gadget_statelistener_stateupdate" is not triggered. Everything else seems to work (e. g. "on_connected"). But I do not know why the statelistener does not work.

Comment: Can you post your INI file (without ID and secret, of course)? There might be an error in the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I do update my EV3, then it works.

https://www.ev3dev.org/docs/tutorials/upgrading-ev3dev/

do this -> Option 2: Upgrading all installed software (slowest)